# What do italics in Chrome devtools elements mean?

Tags: css, google-chrome-devtools

I'm looking at the elements in the hamburger menu of this site:

https://rainbowedit.com/

using Chrome devtools, and the CSS in Elements is in red italics and uneditable. What does this mean? Is there a way to make them editable?

[image: devtools with italic css hilighted]

Answer (score 7):

It seems to be using some kind of JS generated CSS injected in the page. [*styled-components*](https://www.styled-components.com/) is known to do this and the styles are then read-only in the Dev tools.

Source: [Impossible to edit styles in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52732537/1218980)

> I think you're probably seeing the styles injected via "speedy mode"
>   in production. This uses a [special DOM API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet) that Chrome DevTools
>   currently only shows in a read-only capacity. We haven't put in an
>   escape hatch to disable this injection method yet, but [it's being
>   considered](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/2038).

Answer (score 3):

This seems to happen for some styles if you reload the page with Chrome Dev Tools already open on that page. Try closing Dev Tools, reload the page, and then reopen Dev Tools and see if you can then make them editable.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT I'm answering when I have seen this occur, and the solution I have found to make them editable again. Have any advice on how I could make this more answer-y?

Comment: Sadly, reloading didn't fix it for me.

Comment: I use brave browser(V1.11.104), my browser goes into this speedy mode. It is such a hustle to close DevTool every time before refreshing the window. I hope there will be a solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening for me in the last several builds of Chromium.
Only happens when I edit a css rule on a file within an iframe, then reload the iframe. Then I see the locked italicized rule (only for the rule I edited).

I do not think "speedy mode" is in play.

I have reported the behaviour @ [Chromium Bugs](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1289477)

Comment: Thanks for submitting the bug! I've starred it because I too am being annoyed by this behavior. Hope they can get the fix implemented soon.